# IBAction always returns 0 of clicked index in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, row, nsindexpath

Below is what I have.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:999999];
    // setting image to button...
    return cell;    
}
```

In IB, I have set action to this button...

```
- (IBAction)clickedCellAction:(id)sender {

    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [mainTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

    NSLog(@"row==%d", clickedButtonPath.row);
}
```

Now when I run this, I always get `row==0` in iOS 7.

However it gives proper row== in iOS6.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I used...

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:mainTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [mainTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSLog(@"row index---%d", indexPath.row);
```